# Why does my UPDATE trigger "Syntax error in string in query expression" error?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-update

I can execute an Access SQL `INSERT` statement without error, but when I attempt an `UPDATE` with the code below, it throws the error:

> "Syntax error in string in query expression".

Why does that happen and how can I fix it?

Here is my code..

```
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    If txtName.Text = Nothing Or dtpDateBirth.Text = Nothing Or txtPhoneNumber.Text = Nothing Or txtEmail.Text = Nothing Or txtID.Text = Nothing Or mtbNPWP.Text = Nothing Or rtbAddress.Text = Nothing Or txtVillage.Text = Nothing Or txtSubDistrict.Text = Nothing Or txtCity.Text = Nothing Or txtPostalCode.Text = Nothing Or txtEmergencyName.Text = Nothing Or txtEmergencyNumber.Text = Nothing Or txtEmergencyEmail.Text = Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No data has been update", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No data edit")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Call koneksi()
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("update t_customer set name='" & txtName.Text & "', date_birth='" & dtpDateBirth.Text & "', phone_number='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', email='" & txtEmail.Text & "', id='" & txtID.Text & "', npwp='" & mtbNPWP.Text & "', address='" & rtbAddress.Text & "', village='" & txtVillage.Text & "', sub_district='" & txtSubDistrict.Text & "', city='" & txtCity.Text & "', postal_code='" & txtPostalCode.Text & "', gender='" & gen & "', emergency_name='" & txtEmergencyName.Text & "', phone_emergency='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', email_emergency='" & txtEmergencyEmail.Text & "' where [codeCust]='" & txtIDCust.Text, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Update data success!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
    End If
    Call disabled()
    Call showData()
End Sub
```

Comment: `name` is a keyword, try `[name]` but then you also should not be building your statements this way, parameters are the only way you should be taking user input into an SQL statement.

Comment: You're missing the closing single quote where you set codeCust 
 at the very end of your sql which is causing the syntax error, but now is a great opportunity to look into sql parameters. Those not only help against injection attacks, but allow you to query with special characters and not have to worry about things like missing single quotes.

Comment: [VB.Net posts for Access with parameter queries](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvb.net%5D+access+parameter+query)

Comment: I trying to add closing single quote. But now my error is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" :( is because from keyword 'gender' ? cause i had radio buttons to create gender option. #bad language, sorry :(

Comment: `txtName.Text = Nothing Or dtpDateBirth.Text = Nothing` what is this all about, it will not work. Try `If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtpDateBirth.Text) OrElse` etc...

Answer (score 2):

As HansUp has suggested with the link you should be using parameters. Also you are not disposing the command. Also AFAIK (I thought) you needed the open the connection before you can ExecuteNonQuery. As for the Data Mismatch youre experiencing, I think it's because you have a ' in the where clause that shouldnt be there, assuming that the ID is an INT.

```
    Using OledbConn As New OleDbConnection("Conn String")

        OledbConn.Open()
        Using t_customerCMD As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE t_customer SET [Col1]=@Col1,[Col2]=@Col2 WHERE [codeCust]=@codeCust", OledbConn)
            With t_customerCMD
                .Parameters.Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@Col2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@codeCust", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtIDCust.Text) 'Assumes ID is integer
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End Using
        OledbConn.Close()

    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: `Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", TextBox1.Text)`, please don't use `AddWithValue`, use `Add` and specify the type; otherwise it is inferred and **can be wrong**...

Comment: I am yet to see where AddWithValue infers the wrong type on simple types, but you're right, it is more strictly acceptable to explicitly specify the parameter with a defined type

Comment: Dan Guzman - [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) | Joel Coehoorn - [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) please check these articles out, worth a read.

Comment: I will surly give them a read. I have modified my answer to use .Add. The type and length arguments I will leave up to the developer

Comment: thanks for the update, it is indeed the better solution.

Comment: Just for the record, I think it should be mentioned that using an update command without a WHERE clause could have devastating results.

Comment: I just updated the answer, I think his problem is a ' in the where clause and I assume that the ID is an int, so the string in textbox would need converted

Comment: Is that a valid way to send the value to the parameter? I don't see an overload that lets it work that way. Just size, and SourceColumn after the first two arguments.

Comment: @CharlesMay I am 99.9% pretty sure it will work that way, though I will admit, I've been using AddWithValue almost exclusively.

Comment: I don't think your `Add` methods are correct.  No overload of the `Add` method that takes a size parameter also takes a value.  I think you need something like this:  `.Parameters.Add("@Col1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am pretty sure the Size argument is optional. I dont have time to test it at the moment.

Comment: Size is optional yes, but you are passing the _value_ (e. g. TextBox1.Text) into the method.  No overload for the `Add` method takes the value of the parameter.  In addition, you cannot use `SqlDbType` with an `OleDbParameter`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for correcting me. I have run some tests and I can concur.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who helped me. I thank you very much. This problem has been resolved.
this is my completion code, which I can finally do to update the database.

```
   Sub updateData()
    Call gender()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(dtpDateBirth.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhoneNumber.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtID.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(mtbNPWP.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbAddress.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtVillage.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSubDistrict.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCity.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPostalCode.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmergencyName.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmergencyNumber.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmergencyEmail.Text) Then
        MsgBox("No data has been update", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No data edit")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Try
            Call koneksi()
            Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("update t_customer set name='" & txtName.Text & "', date_birth='" & dtpDateBirth.Text & "', phone_number='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', email='" & txtEmail.Text & "', id='" & txtID.Text & "', npwp='" & mtbNPWP.Text & "', address='" & rtbAddress.Text & "', village='" & txtVillage.Text & "', sub_district='" & txtSubDistrict.Text & "', city='" & txtCity.Text & "', postal_code='" & txtPostalCode.Text & "', gender='" & gen & "', emergency_name='" & txtEmergencyName.Text & "', phone_emergency='" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "', email_emergency='" & txtEmergencyEmail.Text & "' where [codeCust]=@codeCust", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("codeCust", CType(txtIDCust.Text, String))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                MsgBox("Update data success!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Because I use the radio button for gender options, I added this so that gender can be changed.

```
Private Sub gender()
    Call koneksi()
    Dim str As String
    str = "Insert into t_customer([gender]) Values (?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, conn)
    If rdnMale.Checked = True Then
        gen = rdnMale.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("gender", CType(gen, String)))
    Else
        gen = rdnFemale.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use a parameter on only one of your variables?  Your code is still wide open to being hacked with sql injection.  You should use parameters for all of your variables.

Comment: For the record, TextBox.Text is already a string and need not be converted to String. cmd.Parameters.Add("codeCust", CType(txtIDCust.Text, String)) Can be simplified to just cmd.Parameters.Add("codeCust", txtIDCust.Text)